# error: "PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION" is not defined

Tags: protocol-buffers, gem5

I am trying to build Gem5 for simulations and I am new to it. I followed the steps mentioned in the following website http://www.gem5.org/Dependencies and I've installed all the necessary files as mentioned. When I run the following command to  build it 
$ scons build/X86/gem5.opt --force-lto
it gives me the following error

build/X86/proto/packet.pb.h:16:15: error: "PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]

[Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqRuf.png)
I tried googling the error but couldn't find any solutions
can someone guide me on how to solve this problem

Comment: When reporting build errors, always give the following: 1) What is your gem5 revision? 2) What is your OS revision and the version of all relevant packages? E.g., I built gem5 7bfb7f3a43f382eb49853f47b140bfd6caad0fb8
 fine on Ubuntu 18.04, which has GCC 7.3.0 and package `protobuf-compiler` at 3.0.0. Also tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. After try several ways to solve the problem. I found this issue may be caused by protobuf. I reinstalled the protobuf, it cannot work.

But I uninstall protobuf. The gem5 can pass build.

But when building it, the warning message show.

Warning: Protocol buffer compiler (protoc) not found.
         Please install protobuf-compiler for tracing support.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: This is fixed in protobuf v3.7.1

---

I just ran into this as well. See [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5129#issuecomment-481786418).

You can either:

- manually update the generated protobuf headers with the correct macro and version
- or you can remove the `-Werror=undef` flag for protobuf source files, if you are sure the versions are compatible.